# Hide keyboard does not work with Webview for UITests run on iPadAir and IPad Air 2 simulators

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview, xcode-ui-testing

Hide keyboard does not work with webview on iPadAir and IPad Air 2. I created a swift UITest to enter a username and password in a Webview but hide keyboard after entering the username does not work- tapping hide keyboard clicks elsewhere on the webview which causes the webview to refresh. This results in clearing out the username field before entering the password. The test then fails because it is trying to log in with just the password field populated and the username field cleared out.

This only happens on iPad Air and iPad Air 2. I need to run the tests against the iPad Air simulator on CI. It works fine on iPad 2. Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: Can you post a code example for entering the username and password with dummy data?

Comment: let usernameTextField = app.webViews.textFields.element
waitForElementToAppear(usernameTextField)
XCTAssert(usernameTextField.exists)
usernameTextField.tap()
usernameTextField.typeText(username)
app.keyboards.buttons["Hide keyboard"].tap()

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It wasn't actually clicking HideKeyboard. It would click outside, somewhere else, that caused the webview to refresh.
I fixed the test by clicking an image on the webview after entering the username. This got rid of the keyboard without refreshing the webview.